# Painting Ownerdrawn CStatic with Calculated HRGN

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, paint

I have a class which inherits from `CStatic`, which is owner drawn and calculates the region the window should have using `SetWindowRgn`.
In my `DrawItem` override I attempt to use `FillRgn` passing in the same region as was calculated but the method returns FALSE. The [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6df5dz8f.aspx) says

> Return Value: Nonzero if the function is successful; otherwise 0.

But when I `GetLastError` the message is "The operation completed successfully".

The window's region is definitely getting the set fine as I have managed to receive `WM_LBUTTONUP` messages.

Here is my class:

### .h file

```
class Country : public CStatic
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(Country)

public:
    Country(HBITMAP hBm, CPoint point);
    virtual ~Country(); 

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    CPoint m_point;
    HBITMAP m_hBm;
    BITMAP m_bm;
    HDC m_dcBm;
    HRGN m_hRgn;

    void CreateWindowRgn();

public: 
    void CreateCountryWindow(CWnd * pParent);
    afx_msg void OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
    virtual void DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct);
};
```

### .cpp

```
void Country::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)
{
    CDC *pDC = CDC::FromHandle(lpDrawItemStruct->hDC);  
    CRgn * clientRgn = CRgn::FromHandle(m_hRgn);        
    CBrush blackBrush(RGB(0,0,0));
    if(!(pDC->FillRgn(clientRgn, &blackBrush)))
    {
        AfxMessageBox(GetLastErrorMessage());
    }
}

void Country::CreateCountryWindow(CWnd * pParent)
{
    if(Create(
        _T(""), 
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_NOTIFY | SS_OWNERDRAW, 
        CRect(m_point.x, QUESTION_PANEL_HEIGHT + m_point.y, m_bm.bmWidth, m_bm.bmHeight),  
        pParent))   
    {
        ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
        CreateWindowRgn();
    }
}

void Country::CreateWindowRgn()
{
    HRGN hTmpRgn;   
    m_hRgn = CreateRectRgn(0,0,m_bm.bmWidth, m_bm.bmHeight);
    for(int i = 0; i < m_bm.bmWidth; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < m_bm.bmHeight; j++)
        {
            COLORREF c = GetPixel(m_dcBm,i,j);
            if(GetRValue(c) < 10 && GetGValue(c) < 10 && GetBValue(c) < 10)                     
            {
                hTmpRgn = CreateRectRgn(i, j, i+1, j+1);                
                CombineRgn(m_hRgn, m_hRgn, hTmpRgn, RGN_XOR);
                DeleteObject(hTmpRgn);
            }           
        }
    }
    SetWindowRgn(m_hRgn, TRUE);     
}

void Country::OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    AfxMessageBox(_T("Hello World"));
    CStatic::OnLButtonUp(nFlags, point);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with most MFC problems the answer lies in the documentation:

> The system does not make a copy of the region. Thus, do not make
>   further function calls with this region handle.

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa930600.aspx)